# tf.layers.batch_normalization( training=is_train) is deprecated, what is the alternative?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

```
is_train = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.bool, name='is_train')
conv_norm = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv, training=self.is_train)
```

this code works 
`tf.layers.batch_normalizaton` is depricated

Are there any alternatives in `tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()`?

I can't find a parameter for "training" in it

Comment: can you explain what training parameter did? maybe it's renamed (e.g. I see trainable which might be the same parameter)

Comment: tf.layers.batch_normalization is deprecated
and I have to use Keras.layers.BatchNormalization
but can't find how to place that training in it
I used trainable I am not sure if it is the same

I used tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(trainable=is_train) 
it returned this error :
 Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed

Comment: when training, the parameter "training=True", and when validate, it is "training=False"

"trainable" works when it is not a tf.bool